# Lennard-Jones vapor-liquid coexistence pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, phase-transition, phase-diagram

No analytical equation of state for the Lennard-Jones substance is known, but, as far as I know, one of the known best approximations is the [Kolafa-Nezbeda equation of state](https://www.ier.unam.mx/%7Emlh/documentos/Miguel/kolafalj.pdf) (given in equations 30-32).

How do I find the vapor-liquid coexistence pressure as a function of temperature starting from the equation of state? Although the article by Kolafa and Nezbeda shows the plotted result and compares it with other equation of states, it does not show an expression for this curve. Knowing the difficulty for the van-der-Waals case, which requires the Maxwell construction, I think a numerical method should be employed to find this curve, but I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two phases to be in equilibrium, they must be at the same
temperature, pressure and chemical potential.
Maxwell's construction is simply a method for finding this point
where the chemical potentials are equal given the equation of state
i.e. the pressure as a function of density and temperature.

The paper you cite gives explicit expressions for the Helmholtz free energy,
so, while you can use the Maxwell construction exactly as for
the van der Waals equation of state, you can also calculate
the chemical potential and pressure as functions of temperature and density
by taking the appropriate derivatives of the Helmholtz free energy,
and find for a given $T$, two $\rho$ values
which give the same pressure and chemical potential. These will be
the two $\rho$ values corresponding to the same temperature in the
phase coexistence curve.

Given the form of the Free energy from the reference, this almost certainly requires you to do this numerically.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add some practical details to the previous answer by user200143
Since the paper expresses the Helmholtz's free energy, it is better to use it to derive the expression of the chemical potential as a function of density and temperature. Once you have the expression to evaluate $\mu(\rho,T)$, the numerical determination of the coexistence curve can be done by solving the set of two equations in the two unknown densities of the coexisting liquid (L) and gas (G), $\rho_L$ and $\rho_G$:
$$
\begin{align}
P(T,\rho_L)&=P(T,\rho_G)\\
\mu(T,\rho_L)&=\mu(T,\rho_G)
\end{align}
$$
In practice, one can fix the temperature, sampling pressure, and chemical potential as functions of the density, starting from low and from high densities. Plotting data as two curves in the $P$-$\mu$ plane, parametrized, one by $\rho_L$ and the other by $\rho_G$ allows us to find the approximate coexistence condition from the values of the densities corresponding to the crossing of the two curves.

Once the approximate coexistence densities have been obtained, any numerical algorithm to solve a system of two non-linear equations can be used to find the accurate solution. It is also easy to get the whole coexistence curve by slowly varying the temperature. The previous coexistence densities are good starting points for solving the system at the new temperature.

Notice that such a direct method works even when Maxwell's construction is impossible. For example, the isotherms are not defined in the whole coexistence region.